# Using recursion to find a character in a string

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am trying to find the first occurrence of a letter in a string. For example, p in apple should return 1. Here is what I have:

```
// Returns the index of the of the character ch
public static int indexOf(char ch, String str) {

    if (str == null || str.equals("")) {
        return -1;
    } else if(ch == str.charAt(0)) {
        return 1+ indexOf(ch, str.substring(1));
    }

    return indexOf(ch, str.substring(1));
}
```

It just doesn't seem to be returning the correct value.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use [`String.indexOf(int ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-)?

Comment: @LutzHorn Homework - care to wager? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt was good, but not quite there. Here is a correct implementation based off yours:

```
public static int indexOf(char ch, String str) {
    // Returns the index of the of the character ch

    if (str == null || str.equals("")) {
        // base case: no more string to search; return -1
        return -1;
    } else if (ch == str.charAt(0)) {
        // base case: ch is at the beginning of str; return 0
        return 0; 
    }

    // recursive step
    int subIndex = indexOf(ch, str.substring(1));

    return subIndex == -1 ? -1 : 1 + subIndex;
}
```

There were two problems with your attempt:

In the `else if` part, you had found the character, so the right thing to do was stop the recursion, but you were continuing it.

In your last return statement, you needed to be adding 1 to the recursive call (if the character was eventually found), as a way of accumulating the total index number.

Comment: I was going to upvote but noticed that there's at least one flaw in your logic. If you try a letter that is not in the string you just get the index of the last letter.

Comment: @PaulSasik Looks like you and I noticed that at the same time. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Cool. +1 and some other words

Comment: @JLRishe +1 for your recursive step. Really intelligent I would say. In recursive step I was doing "return 1+indexOf(s.substr(1,s.length()),c)" in C++ that worked fine except for the case Paul Sasik pointed.

Answer (score 7):

I'll give you some hints:

1. When you've found the letter, you don't need to recurse further. Additionally, think about what you should be returning in this case.
2. When do you recurse, also think about what the function should return.
3. Is there anything special you need to do if the recursive call returns `-1`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another variation. Instead of calling substring you could modify the function a bit to pass the next index to check. Notice that the recursion is initiated with index 0. (You could actually start on any index. There is also some error checking in case the letter isn't found. Looking for x in apple will return -1.)

```
public static void main(String []args){  
    System.out.println("Index: " + indexOf('e', "apple", 0));
    System.out.println("Index: " + indexOf('x', "apple", 0));
    System.out.println("Index: " + indexOf('p', "Mississippi", 3));
    System.out.println("Index: " + indexOf('p', "Mississippi", 908));
}

public static int indexOf(char ch, String str, int idx) {
    // check for garbage data and incorrect indices
    if (str == null || str.equals("") || idx > str.length()-1) 
        return -1;

    // check to see if we meet our condition
    if (ch == str.charAt(idx)) 
        return idx;

    // we don't match so we recurse to check the next character
    return indexOf(ch, str, idx+1);
}
```

Output:

```
Index: 4
Index: -1
Index: 8
Index: -1
```

Comment: `idx = indexOf(ch, str, ++idx);` this makes me cringe. Why not `return indexOf(ch, str, idx + 1)`?

Comment: @JLRishe: I just posted an edit concerning your cringe as your comment landed. :-)

Comment: Indeed you did. :) I still think `idx + 1` is much better here. There's no reason to increment the `idx` variable.

Comment: @JLRishe: +1 Good point. idx+1 is much more readable and intuitive, especially for a newbie. Not sure why I did the prefix thing. for loops on the brain I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Well if we must use recursion then try this:

```
class RecursiveFirstIndexOf {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(indexOf('p', "apple", 0));
}

static int indexOf(char c, String str, int currentIdx) {

    if (str == null || str.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    return str.charAt(0) == c ? currentIdx : indexOf(c, str.substring(1), ++currentIdx);

}}
```

Comment: thats a question not a answer

Comment: What I meant was indexOf is already provided by Java, so why not just use it instead of writing method to do the same thing ?

Comment: i know, but the question says: "using recursion" and not any build in method. anyway this is not a question. maybee a comment.

Comment: The only reason to recursively look for the index of a letter in a string is to practice recursion. That's the key word: practice. The OP is probably just picking up Java and this is homework, or a lab assignment or some such academic thing.

Answer (score -2):

Why not doing it straight forward?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abcdef";
    for (int idx = 0; idx < str.length(); idx++) {
        System.out.printf("Expected %d, found %d\n", idx, indexOf(str.charAt(idx), str, 0));
    }
    System.out.printf("Expected -1, found %d\n", indexOf(str.charAt(0), null, 0));
}

public static int indexOf(char ch, String str, int index) {
    if (str == null || index >= str.length()) return -1;
    return str.charAt(index) == ch ? index : indexOf(ch, str, ++index);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Expected 0, found 0
Expected 1, found 1
Expected 2, found 2
Expected 3, found 3
Expected 4, found 4
Expected 5, found 5
Expected -1, found -1
```

Comment: I'll never understand why people use `++variable` when they apparently think `variable + 1` is too many characters.

Answer (score -3):

first of all : **Recursion** has two pillars, **Base Case** and **General Case**.

**Base Case** (the termination point) is the one where **Recursion** terminates and **General Case** as the name implies is where the program keeps executing until it finds  **Base Case**

you may try this example, where `count` is a global `static` variable

```
public static int indexOf(char ch, String str)
{
  // Returns the index of the of the character ch
  if (str == null || str.Equals(""))     //Base Case
  {
     if (count != 0)
     {
        if(str.Length == 0)
           return -1;  
        return count;
     }
     else
        return -1;          
  }
  else if (ch == str.CharAt(0))          //Base Case  
     return 1 + count; 
  count++;
  return indexOf(ch, str.Substring(1));  //General Case
}
```

Comment: Using a static variable for this is not a good idea. This also has an off-by-one bug and produces the completely wrong result if the string doesn't contain the requested character.

Comment: @JLRishe as per you instructions i've fixed the 'character not present case', and i have used static just because i didn't want the prototype of user's function to changed (i.e. to use extra parameters), anyways thanks for your comments.