# find last occurrence of a character in a given string recursively in C

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to find last occurrence of a character in a given string recursively. I've written code for first occurrence. How can I write for last occurrence? Here is my code for first occurrence:

Instead of giving vote down , give idea please ????

```
#include <stdio.h>

int first_occurance(const char *s,char ch);

int main()
{

    int x;
    x = first_occurance("testtest", 'e');
    printf("%d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
int first_occurance(const char *s,char ch)
{
    int check;
    if (*s == '\0') {   // at null character stop it
        return -1;
    }
    else if (*s == ch) { // match the specified char return
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        check = 1 + first_occurance(s + 1, ch); // else try next char
        if (check == 0) // not matching sum of check will be zero -1 + 1
            return -1;
        return check;   // return index
    }

}
```

Example for last occurance

string is : testtest

returned value is: 5

Comment: Is it homework? because there is `strrchr()`. Also, `if (*s == '\0')` is not enough, you are potentially dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, there is no real performance hit in a common application if you check for `s == NULL`. And yes you still can cause undefined behavior by passing an uninitialized pointer, but this eliminates one chance for UB.

Comment: I don't understand your edit with the example - if the string is "testtest" and the return value is "5", what character are you searching for?  Position 5 is "t" but the last occurrence of "t" is at position 7 (8 if you are using a 1-based index).  Can you clarify on what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @iharob  Standard C string functions do not check whether a pointer is equal to NULL. It is the client code that should check whether it passes NULL.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes and it's for performance reasons AFAIK, so if you write a function to handle pointers, it's not a bad idea to check for `NULL`.

Comment: @iharob  I prefer to follow the general convention for basic string functions. Though sometimes it is a good idea to check to NULL within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the best solution! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int last_occurence( const char *s, char c )
{
    if ( !*s ) return -1;

    int n = last_occurence( s + 1, c );

    return n + ( n != -1 || *s == c );
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *s =  "testtest";
    const char *p;

    for ( p = s; *p; ++ p )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", last_occurence( s, *p ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
7
5
6
7
7
5
6
7
```

An alternative return statement in the function can look like

```
return ( *s == c || n != -1 ) ? n + 1 : -1;
```

If you want that the function would return pointer then it can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * last_occurence( const char *s, char c )
{
    if ( !*s ) return NULL;

    char *p = last_occurence( s + 1, c );

    if ( p == NULL && *s == c ) p = ( char * )s;

    return p;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *s =  "testtest";
    const char *p;

    for ( p = s; *p; ++ p )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", last_occurence( s, *p ) - s );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the same as above

```
7
5
6
7
7
5
6
7
```

Comment: `( n == -1 && *s == c ) || ( n != -1 )` simplifies to `(*s == c) || (n != -1)`

Comment: @chux I am sorry. It seems you are right. I will update my post.:)

Comment: It fails for `last_occurence( s, '\0')` - but easy to fix.

Comment: @chux I purposely ignored this case. But as you noticed correctly it is very simply to include this case. It is enough to change the first statement of the function.

Comment: True - The challenge to this post really is the goal to use recursion - even though the a good solution does not need one.  Recursive solutions that use the stack to iterate, though meeting the goal, rapidly use up the stack and give recursion a bad name.  If the string was 'N' characters long, "N' recursions is usually a _bad_ thing - stacks just are not as deep as strings can be long.  Not to take away from you fine answer, OP's coding goal (which may be a professor's goal) is just not a good exercise for recursion.  +1

Comment: @chux  I agree with all you said except the last statement that it is not a good exercise for recursion.:)

Answer (score 1):

After commented `strchr()`, I found a code which has been written by bluepixy. However, why did the people choose voting down instead of helping ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *StrrchrR(const char *s, int c, char *find){
    if(s==NULL) return NULL;
    if(*s == '\0') return (c == '\0') ? (char*)s : find;
    return StrrchrR(s + 1, c, *s == c ? (char*)s : find);
}

char *Strrchr(const char *s, int c){
    return StrrchrR(s, c, NULL);
}
/*
char *Strrchr(const char *s, int c){
    char *ret;
    if(s == NULL)return NULL;
    if(*s=='\0') return (c == '\0') ? (char*)s : NULL;
    if(ret = Strrchr(s + 1, c)) return ret;
    if(*s == c) return (char*)s;
    return NULL;
}
*/    
int main(void){
    const char *str = "abcabdefg";
    char *cp;

    cp=Strrchr(str, '\0');
    printf("%c\n", *--cp);//g
    cp=Strrchr(str, 'b');
    printf("%c\n", *++cp);//d
    cp=Strrchr(str, 'z');
    if(!cp)printf("NULL\n");//NULL
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not really following how this code is the answer to your question, but then, I'm not sure that I fully understand the question to begin with.

Comment: @NewCoder This code is simply wrong. First of all you wrote in your original post that the function must have return type int. You showed the function declaration  Secondly it is not the function char *Strrchr(const char *s, int c) itself that is recursive. And thirdly the code is difficult to read. I do not know who upvoted this your answer but it is evident they are not strong programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a `char` has a corner case of what happens when `c == 0`.  Following handles all `char` values.

```
char *Strrchr(const char *s, int c) {
  while (*s != c) {
    if (*s == 0) {
      return NULL;
    }
    s++;
  }
  // Could there be more?
  if (c) {
    char *p = Strrchr(s + 1, c);
    if (p) {
      return p;
    }
  }
  return (char *) s;
}
```

Some pipelined platforms are speedier with fewer branch possibilities:

```
char *Strrchr_times(const char *s, int c) {
  while (*s * (*s - c)) {  // only 1 test
    s++;
  }
  // Could there be a later match?
  if (*s) {
    char *p = Strrchr_times(s + 1, c);
    if (p) {
      return p;
    }
  }
  return *s == c ? (char *) s : NULL;
}
```

Since there really is no reason for recursion other than an an exercise, below is a non-recursive solution.

```
char *Strrchr_nonrecursive(const char *s, int c) {
  const char *p = NULL;
  do {
    if (*s == c) {
      p = s;
    }
  } while (*s++);
  return (char *) p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three solutions! I hope there's the one solving your problem!

If you search only the last you may use strrchr, but I think you want all the occurences! If you need the position of the last occurence you may compute it using the difference between the value strrchr returns and the pointer of the string!!!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int strchrpos(char *sd, int lp, char s);
int strchrpos2(char *sd, char s);

int strchrpos(char *sd,int lp, char s)
{
    sd+=(++lp);
    while(*sd!=0 && *sd!=s) {
        sd++;lp++;
    }

    return (*sd!=0)?lp:-1;
}

int strchrpos2(char *sd, char s)
{
    static int lp;

    if (sd==NULL) {
    lp=-1;
    return 0;
    }

    sd+=(++lp);
    while(*sd!=0 && *sd!=s) {
        sd++;lp++;
    }

    return (*sd!=0)?lp:-1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[20],* app;
    int p=-1;

    strcpy(str,"testtest");

    puts("searching: s -----------------------------");
    /* If you need ordinal position! */
    while((p=strchrpos(str,p,'s'))>=0)
        printf("%d %s\n",p,str+p);

    puts("searching: t -----------------------------");
    /* if you need the pointer to the substring (std strchr) */
    app=str;
    while( (app=strchr(app,'t'))!=NULL ) {
        printf("%s\n",app);app++;
    }

    puts("searching: t -----------------------------");
    /* If you need ordinal position and you want the
       called function keeps position trace */
    strchrpos2(NULL,0); /* NULL is used as reset */
    while((p=strchrpos2(str,'t'))>=0)
        printf("%d %s\n",p,str+p);

    puts("searching: e -----------------------------");
    /* If you need ordinal position and you want the
       called function keeps position trace */
    strchrpos2(NULL,0); /* NULL is used as reset */
    while((p=strchrpos2(str,'e'))>=0)
        printf("%d %s\n",p,str+p);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is the following:

```
searching: s -----------------------------
2 sttest
6 st
searching: t -----------------------------
testtest
ttest
test
t
searching: t -----------------------------
0 testtest
3 ttest
4 test
7 t
searching: e -----------------------------
1 esttest
5 est
```

Remember:

Function strchrpos: The first time it's called it must receive lp=-1 (last position).

Function strchrpos2: This function cannot be used to parse a string while parsing another string because the  string trace method is based on the use of "static int lp"
inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is C++ code, instead of using C style string, I am using C++ string but idea is same.
Don't use this "int check;" extra variable because it can give wrong results.

```
int indexOf (string s, char c) {

    if (s == "") {
        return -1;
    } else if (s [0] == c) {
            return 1+indexOf(s.substr(1,s.length()),c);
        } else {
        int subIndex = indexOf(s.substr(1,s.length()),c);
           if (subIndex == -1) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return subIndex+1;
            }
        }

}
```

I tweaked first occurrence of character in string. this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22856761/1372290)

Answer (score -1):

```
char myversion_strrchr(char *input,char sub)
{
```

> The idea is to check if input string is null
>
> If not,then check if it contains sub
>
> The point at which we get sub in the input string,we store the current input string in a temp variable and move on to check the rest of the string for the occurence of sub
>
> If the rest of the string contains a sub, then ret_val will store that. And at each point we return ret_val if it is not NULL,otherwise return temp;

```
    char *temp=NULL,*ret_val=NULL;
    if(input[0]=='\0') //check if input string is NULL
        return temp;
    else if(input[0]==sub) // otherwise check if input string starts with sub
        temp=input;// if it does, then store it in a temp variable
    else
        temp=NULL; //if not,then temp variable should be NULL
    ret_val=myversion_strrchr(input+1,sub); //with the rest of the string check if a sub occurs anywhere
    if (ret_val!=NULL) //if a sub occurs in the rest of the string then return that string
        return ret_val;
    else//else,return temp... temp will contain either input string if it starts with sub or it will contain NULL
        return temp;           

}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer as why it answers the question.

Comment: If there is something more I can do to explain my solution,please do let me know.